# How to model a multi-type relationship in KeystoneJS?

Tags: relationship, keystonejs

I have a project where i need to manage some data together with a small team. For this task i'm currently testing KeystoneJs as the CMS system and came to a use case that i can't solve out of the box.

I want to describe a relationship between to a parent type on one side and 2-3 different subpytes on the other.
For example, you can think of an event-log type as the parent, which should have a list of different event types with different properties related to it. Because the order of the events matter for me, i don't want to just add an relationship field for every event type but manage them with a single one.

Because i think that this type of relasionship is not supported by the framework but this should be usual use-case, i want to know how you guys would approach/model this.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73855948/schema-design-for-b2b-site-with-varying-products-using-keystone-6/73876260? I have an answer there that covers some of the decent solves